# Center multiple div vertically and responsively

Tags: html, css

I would like to build a vertical bar with dots on it that are equally spaced vertically. They should stay like that even if the window height change (dot size does not change but space between them changes). I would like to achieve this without using JS. First and last dot should stay on top and bottom of the bar. What is the best way to do this?

I wrote a codepen to make it easier:

```
<div class="wrap-side-bar">
  <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">

    <div class="bar gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemple on codepen](http://codepen.io/impoz/pen/gLbYyY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox. Try the following solution:

```css
* { 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
  justify-content:space-between;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.wrap-side-bar{
  width:30px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  padding:15px 0;
  z-index:-5;
}
.dot {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  z-index:20;
}
.bar{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:10px;
  background-color:green; 
  margin:0 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.gradient{
  background-color:#00ca3e;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#00ca3e, endColorstr=#0018ff);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(7%,#00ca3e), color-stop(100%,#0018ff));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-side-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bar gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. (On firefox the first dot doesn't appear but i don't need firefox support anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following css to achieve this:

```
.wrap-side-bar {
    display:flex; 
    align-item:center; 
    justify-content:space-around; 
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved desired effect with `absolute` positioning of the dots, however it's going to need little additional styles for the smaller heights, but I'm sure you can take it from here :). If it is not what you are looking for any reason let me know, but as you already positioned your `.bar` absolutely I thought it's gonna be OK.

```css
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.wrap-side-bar{
 width:30px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 padding:15px 0;
  z-index:-5;
}
.dot {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  z-index:20;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}
.dot:first-child {
  top: 0;
}
.dot.two {
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  top: 33%;
}
.dot.three {
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  top: 66%;
}
.dot:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
}
.bar{
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:10px;
 background-color:green; 
 margin:0 10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 z-index:-1;
}

.gradient{
 background-color:#00ca3e;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#00ca3e, endColorstr=#0018ff);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(7%,#00ca3e), color-stop(100%,#0018ff));
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap-side-bar">
  <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="bar gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot two gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot three gradient"></div>
    <div class="dot gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is a great approach but when lowering the height the space ratio between dots is not fix (they start to have different size)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of wscourge answer [updated_jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q05wkau/1/) with a better positionning of the dots.

Firsts three points

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

and for the last one

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```css
* { 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.wrap-side-bar{
 width:30px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 padding:15px 0;
  z-index:-5;
}
.dot {
  background-color: gren;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  z-index:20;
  position: relative;
}
.bar{
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:10px;
 background-color:green; 
 margin:0 10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 z-index:-1;
}

.gradient::after, .gradient-bar {
 background-color:#00ca3e;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#00ca3e, endColorstr=#0018ff);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #00ca3e 7%, #0018ff 100%);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(7%,#00ca3e), color-stop(100%,#0018ff));
 }
.dot::after {
position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top:50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-side-bar">
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">

<div class="bar gradient-bar"></div>
<div class="dot gradient"></div>
<div class="dot gradient"></div>
<div class="dot gradient"></div>
<div class="dot gradient"></div>
</div>
</div>
```